# Does every directed set admit a totally ordered quotient of the same size?

Tags: order-theory

A set $P$ with a transitive and relfexive relation $\leq_{1}$ is called a directed set (upward directed set in this case) if for all $a,b\in P$ there is a $c\in P$ such that $a\leq_{1} c$ and $b\leq_{1} c$.

Assume that the relation $\leq_{1}$ is also antisymmetric (that $(P,\leq_{1})$ is a poset). Is there a totally ordered set $(S,\leq_{2})$ and a surjective monotone function $f:P\rightarrow S$ such that if $a,b\in P$ are distinct elements such that $a\leq_{1} b$, then $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are also distinct elements of $S$.

I suspect that such an $S$ and such an $f$ exist for every poset, but I haven't found a reference. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - this can be proved using the axiom of choice in the form of Zorn's lemma. The result is called [Szpilrajn's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szpilrajn_extension_theorem), and many further results along these lines are known; for example, [every well-founded partial order can be extended to a well-order](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4124649/28111).

Interestingly, the use of choice is unavoidable: Szpilrajn's theorem is *not* provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= set theory without the axiom of choice) alone. Specifically, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are **amorphous** sets (= sets which cannot be partitioned into two infinite pieces); no amorphous set can be linearly ordered, but every set can be partially ordered (just make all elements incomparable to each other).

Comment: I see. This looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I think I actually remember this result from a set theory course.